# How to retrieve list views of any salesforce object using API?

Tags: api, rest, soap, salesforce

I want to retrieve all list views of any salesforce object through API. How to do that?

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but, using the REST API and Salesforce's query language, you could use the endpoint:

```
{your instance url}/services/data/v32.0/query?q=SELECT Id,Name FROM {object type}
```

OR

Use the endpoint:

```
{your instance url}/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/{object type}/listviews
```

Some examples:

To get all listviews: https://na16.salesforce.com/services/data/v32.0/query?q=SELECT Id,Name FROM ListView

To get all listviews with object type of account: https://na16.salesforce.com/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/Account/listviews

In PHP:

```
$url = "{your instance url}/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/Account/listviews";
$headers = array('Authorization: OAuth ' . {your access token});
$ch = curl_init ();  
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );  
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );  
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE );  
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);  

$requestBody = curl_exec ($ch);
$result = json_decode($requestBody, true);
```

Of course you'll need to login first through OAUTH to get an access token and instance URL.

Answer (score 1):

If it's SOAP api that you are looking for, it's called `describeSObject` - for specific object, or 'describeGlobal' - for all your org's data.

See the reference link below for SOAP message:
http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Sample_SOAP_Messages_(10.0_API)

Answer (score 0):

Create a [StandardSetController](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm) for given object (the query you'll use to instantiate it can have "LIMIT 1" or something, no need to select all records). Then use `getListViewOptions()`.

Remember that it will return views visible for current user (so only the public ones + ones marked as "visible only to me').

**EDIT:**
To access it from outside (via SOAP or REST API)...
I'm not aware of method to get these with REST calls I'm afraid. You might have to write a bit of Apex and expose a custom REST resource that will return this data. It's not that hard, see http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm for examples.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I am using PHP and trying to show list of views of any sObject using API.

Comment: I search in google and I came to know that, SAlesforce provide matadata API using SOAP only. https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=integrate_what_is_api.htm&language=en_US . But I can`t use SOAP due to some restrictions. So can anyone tell me how to access list view of salesforce using http request from PHP?

Comment: Thank you. I saw your link. I can`t use any apex code, because I am implementing a web app in PHP where User will provide their Salesforce login credential and I have to fetch all Objects from Salesforce. Then they will select any Object and I have to show them all listviews for that selected object. So there is no fixed Salesforce Instance wheere I can write some Apex code.

Comment: No metadata API, no Apex... Sorry, if there's a way I'm not aware of any, maybe somebody else will post a better answer. You can also try asking on dedicated stack site: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com But I'm very doubtful. The `getListViewOptions()` would return you list of IDs, not their definitions (so you could recreate the columns & filter criteria in PHP) :( Best I could come up with was "recent items" (REST call to URL like `/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/Account`